# OLE Automation Word 2013 fails when a second instance of word is running

Tags: office-interop

I sometimes get 'Call rejected by callee' Exception from HResult 0x80010001, when calling Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document.get_Fullname().

I noticed this is happening when 'outlook preview attachments' is enabled and someone is previewing a Word document inside outlook. Apparently when one previews a Word document, a second instance of WinWord.exe is created. Next OLE calls to Word probably goes to the wrong instance.

After closing outlook, OLE access to Word works like expected.
Any idea how I can avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0):

What code do you use for creating a Word Application instance?

The fact is that Outlook uses Word as an email editor and for rendering HTML markup. So, that is why you may see a Word process in the list of running processes.

Comment: wordApplication = (Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");

Comment: I know outlook is responsible for the second instance, there should be a way to get the right instance for my OLE interactions, not the one used by outlook (or any other application using embedded word)